# Go, basic access authentication

Tags: passwords, go, basic-authentication

Does Google Go support decoding of [basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) calls? How do I get the username and password from the http.Request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go does not seem to intercept basic authentication when it is typed as an URL in a browser, but it does allow one to get it from some other applications calling it.

For example, using a simple Python code for [HTTP JSON RPC](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/python-json-rpc):

```
from jsonrpc import ServiceProxy
access = ServiceProxy("http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8080/")
print access.getinfo()
```

And in Go calling:

```
// r *http.Request
r.Header["Authorization"]
```

One gets this string:

```
[Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz]
```

And

```
dXNlcjpwYXNz
```

Base-64 decoded gives

```
user:pass
```

So some basic authentication in Go is possible, although it might not be something one can rely on.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to get the user-provided authentication info, but you can provide the valid username and password for HTTP Basic Authentication by calling [`SetBasicAuth`](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.SetBasicAuth).